# sails.js not lifting after data migration

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I use sails.js with MongoDB as primary place for my models. I've just completed data migration from production DB, and now there are several hundred thousands documents in some collections.

But there is a problem. When I try to `sails lift` i'm getting the following log:

```
...

verbose: views hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Setting default Express view engine to ejs...
verbose: Starting ORM...
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

And i see no reasons why this happens. There is enought free memory. Database is not too big, i have much bigger Mongo databases, working well and fast at the same node configuration. Does anyone have any ideas where to dig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the problem lurked in SailsJS attempts to auto-migrate relatively big database. In my case i just had to change `migrate: 'alter'` to `migrate: 'safe'` in `config/models.js`.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with mysql, this is clearly a bug... 900 records was big enough to get this issue